# Hide Python type hints in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Is there some way to hide/toggle Python's [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in PyCharm?

Code with a lot of type hints is sometimes harder to understand and such a feature could help with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding type hints isn't currently possible in PyCharm. There is an open ticket  [PY-40996](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40996) requesting the feature.

In the ticket one of the developers elaborates on possible UX implementations so you can contribute your opinion and also support the ticket by leaving a vote.

It is possible to make hint adjustments in PyCharm for *Angular*, *JavaScript*, *SQL* and *TypeScript* by going to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Inlay Hints`, but not yet for Python type hints.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setting > Intentions > Python and uncheck both "Add type hints..." boxes.

Comment: This does not seem to work. At least for a given example of 
`def test(a: str, b: str) -> str`, It does not show what I would expect: `def test(a, b):`

Comment: I have tried it and it worked for me. You mean to remove the menu item from the light bulb menu, right?

Comment: No, I literally mean hide the source-code-text (in this case: `: str`, `: str` and `-> str`).